# React Native Router Flux Redirect Scene on Login Example

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm looking for an example of using React Native Router Flux to redirect the user to a new scene once authentication has been validated. Assuming I have defined my router component like so:

`<Router>
     <Scene key="root">
         <Scene key="login" component={Login} title="Login" initial={true} hideNavBar="true" duration={1} />
         <Scene key="home" component={Home} title="Home" hideNavBar="true" duration={1} />
     </Scene>
</Router>`

- What needs to be updated in the `<Router>` to redirect from `Login` to `Home`?
- If my `Router` component is nested within a `Drawer` component, where/how will I update the state to specify that my user is logged in?

Comment: Are you by chance using redux to manage your application state?

Comment: No. I'm not. Does it matter?

Comment: Yeah if you did you can just call Actions['home']();

Answer (score 1):

you should use Actions.home() in login component as soon as authentication is completed. Router component doesn't need to change.

and for the second question, you can't have global states(unless you really want to complicate a simple app). to use one, you have to use Redux or similar libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to redirect is to use Actions.home() once your authentication is completed. Since you are not using redux to manage your application state. Things get complicated.

I believe you are looking for solution to know whether the user is loggedin or not in future cases. I believe your best bet would be asyncstorage. Just store a variable is_loggedin to true. In future cases you can check this variable to determine if user is logggedin.

But I seriously recommend using Redux/Reflux. it will be much better.